# Как скачать все сообщения telegram с помощью Telegram API

Tags: python, pyqt5, telegram

Для моего приложения необходимо скачать все текстовые сообщения с Telegram в формате json как это можно сделать в обычном desktop. 
Желательно ответ на python.

Answer (score 1):

Как альтернативу Pyrogram можно использовать оффициальную(как я понял) библиотеку для python telethon. Я бы сказал, что она более настраиваемая, чем pyrogram, и для нее удобнее сделать свой интерфейс взаимодействия (в моем случае PyQt5). Хотя есть и один минус – telethon почти полностью ассинхронен. Вот код:

```
async def get_messages(self):
    chats = []
    i = 0
    async for dialog in self.client.iter_dialogs():
        chats.append({'name': dialog.name,
                      'id': dialog.message.from_id,
                      'messages': []})

        async for message in self.client.iter_messages(dialog.name):
            chats[i]['messages'].append({'text': message.message,
                                         'id': message.from_id,
                                         'date': message.date})
        i += 1
    return chats
```

Comment: а в чем минус асинхронности?

Comment: Не очень удобно использовать в небольших приложениях или со сторонними фреймворками типа PyQt, потому что надо решить проблему запуска 2 event loop-ов. Через threading я вроде не смог решить.

Comment: На данный момент проблем с асинхронностью не будет если использовать библиотеку qasync которая разрешает работать со стандартным с asyncio на QEventLoop

Answer (score 0):

Удобный экспорт доступен только в официальных приложениях Telegram для десктопов.
Однако вы можете воспользоваться библиотекой Pyrogram и написать программу, где с использованием [iter_dialogs()](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/iter_dialogs#pyrogram.Client.iter_dialogs) и [iter_history()](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/iter_history#pyrogram.Client.iter_history) перебрать все диалоги, сохраняя их. Примеры использования приводятся там же. Проблем возникнуть не должно.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. Я поискал и решил попробовать с telethon, но это помоему слишком низкоуровневая библиотека для моей задачи, а вот Pyrogram как раз